# concatenate both two contents or image and content on one button, c# code needed

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to paste an image on multiple buttons using find resource in MainWindow source code and window resources in XAML. But the problem is that, image removes the button content. How to fix it??
May I paste image at border corner or any other solution of this problem?

**.cs**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, Routed Event Args e) 
{ 
   Button button = (Button)sender; 
   if (isGroupOpen == true) 
   { 
      List<Button> buttonlistA = new List<Button>(); 
      buttonlistA.Add(button); 
      button.Content = FindResource("Play1");
   }
}
```

**.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources> 
   <Image x:Key="Play1" x:Shared="false" Name="button" Source="image.png" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="30px,-20px,-20px,30px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"> 
   </Image> 
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Might I trouble you for a glass of code?

Comment: SO won't just write code for you. Please show us what you have tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: @RandomStranger      private void button_Click(object sender, Routed Event Args e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            if (is Group Open == true)
            {
                List<Button> button listA = new List<Button>();


                button list A.Add(button);

                button.Content = Find Resource("Play1");

Comment: @RandomStranger in x.m.l                                      <Window.Resources>
        

        <Image x:Key="Play1" x:Shared="false" Name="button"   Source="image.png" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="30px,-20px,-20px,30px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            
        </Image>
       
    </Window.Resources>

Comment: Short answer: don't do it. You have your image in xaml, you can have your buttons in xaml, you can bring them together in xaml. Also, your button content can be __pretty much anything__, you just design some visual, then place it in a button and the button will contain the visual.

Comment: @grek40 i have multiple buttons and multiple lists , and images are pasted at runtime. if button goes to list 1 then it get image A on it if it goes to list 2 it gets image B and so on...

Comment: Sounds like you can provide a list-specific `Button.Style` where all buttons in one list have the same icon but buttons in another list have a different icon

Comment: Also I don't understand "Images are pasted at runtime". In the question, the image is a resource, created from a static image filename

Comment: lists are created acording to conditions. when button goes to a list it gets a specific image. means image will be according to list

Answer (score 0):

I give you a little example to experiment with. As commented, you shouldn't rely on code behind to much, when trying to define the visual representation of something in WPF. Since you didn't show much of your code, it's impossible to give a precise answer for your specific problem instance, still this answer can give you an idea how visible design and functionality can be separated.

In the following example, there is one initial button and a checkbox. When you click the button, a new button is spawned in List A or List B (depending on the `CheckBox.IsChecked`), with an icon and with a `Command` that handles clicks.

The following assumes that your project contains images `/Images/Yes.png` `/Images/No.png`. You may adjust the actual image properties as you need.

The code

```
public class ButtonDescription
{
    public object ButtonContent { get; set; }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ButtonDescription> ButtonListA { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ButtonDescription> ButtonListB { get; set; }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonListA = new ObservableCollection<ButtonDescription>();
        ButtonListB = new ObservableCollection<ButtonDescription>();
        grid1.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        if (TargetDescriptor.IsChecked == true)
        {
            ButtonListA.Add(new ButtonDescription { ButtonContent = button.Content, ButtonCommand = ApplicationCommands.Open });
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonListB.Add(new ButtonDescription { ButtonContent = button.Content, ButtonCommand = ApplicationCommands.Close });
        }
    }

    private void Open_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Open");
    }
    private void Close_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Close");
    }
}
```

The xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Executed="Open_Executed"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Executed="Close_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Button content templates with image before text content -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonContentA">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/Yes.png" Margin="3" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonContentB">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/No.png" Margin="3" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Common style -->
        <Style  x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 3"/>
        </Style>

        <!-- Specific style for A -->
        <Style x:Key="buttonStyleA" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource buttonContentA}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>
        </Style>

        <!-- Specific style for B -->
        <Style x:Key="buttonStyleB" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource buttonContentB}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
        </Style>

        <!-- Let the list items of type ButtonDescription be shown as Button -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonsListItemTemplate">
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonContent}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="TargetDescriptor" Content="Copy to List A" IsChecked="True" Margin="3 5"/>
            <Button Content="Click me please" Click="Button_Click" Margin="3 5" MinHeight="28"/>

            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="List A" Margin="3 5"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonListA}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonsListItemTemplate}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyleA}"/>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
            </ItemsControl>

            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="List B" Margin="3 5"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonListB}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonsListItemTemplate}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyleB}"/>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```